# How would i go about deriving a formula to describe the projectile path of an object moving over a rotating ellipsoid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, projectile

The ellipsoid is rotating at a rate of $7.3*10^{-5} Radians/Second$. The height radius is $6.358*10^6 meters$ and the width radius is $6.3781*10^6 meters$. And gravity plays a large role because it has a mass of $5.97*10^24kg$.

This ellipsoid happens to be earth. I was hoping to derive a formula to calculate ballistic trajectories based on initial location, velocity, angle, and direction. I've gotten as far as $Tv =  (Cos \theta)(465) $. That just gives the tangential velocity at the surface based on  latitude. But it doesn't take into account the ellipsoid shape, or calculate the path at all. I'm pretty clueless about this kind of three dimensional mathematics. I'm not asking for anyone to do this for me, but if you want to I would like to take a look at how it's done. I just want some guide lines for deriving such a formula.

I think all I need to do is calculate a suborbital path and then factor in the starting location to find the end location based on the rotation. I know it would be a lot easier to assume the earth is spherical but just for fun I thought i would make it as accurate as possible. Neglecting air resistance because that's beyond my abilities.

Comment: $5.97x10^24kg$. Did you mean $5.97 \times 10^{24}\text{ kg}$?

Comment: yea, whoops. ill fix it

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the calculation for a spherical Earth with be easier.  Do that first to get yourself started.  Then do it again for the ellipsoid.  The main difference conceptually will be that gravity will depend on the latitude in addition to the altitude.  You'll still have the same basic equations of motion, but the integral will be more complicated. (It will also depend on the direction that your projectile travels since, for example, going around the poles will be different than going around the equator because of the dependence on latitude.)